# Binding HTML changes to a model

Tags: angularjs

I have a data structure that contains the structure of a navigation menu.

```
function linksRarrange($scope, linksData) {
    $scope.links = [
        {
            text: 'Menu Item 1',
            url: '#',
            submenu: []
        }, {
            text: 'Menu Item 2',
            url: '#',
            submenu: [
                {
                    text: 'Sub-menu Item 3',
                    url: '#',
                    submenu: []
                }, {
                    text: 'Sub-menu Item 4',
                    url: '#',
                    submenu: [
                        {
                            text: 'Sub-sub-menu Item 5',
                            url: '#',
                            submenu: [
                                {
                                    text: 'Sub-sub-menu Item 6',
                                    url: '#',
                                    submenu: []
                                }
...

    ];
}
```

And I am using jQuery UI to rearrange them. The problem is that I am not sure how can I use a 2-way binding in this case so that the `links` object will be updated upon changes.

this is the HTML:

```
<div class="nav-manage clearfix" ng-app="linksManager">

    <div
        class="links-arrange"
        ng-controller="linksRarrange"
        ng-init="submenu = links;"
    >
        <ul
            class="ng-list-level"
            model-subset="submenu"
            ui-jq="sortable"
            ng-include="'inner-list.html'"
        ></ul>
    </div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="inner-list.html">

        <li ui-jq="droppable" ng-repeat="link in submenu">
            <a href="{{link.url}}">{{link.text}}</a>
            <ul
                class="ng-list-level"
                ng-class="{'empty hidden': !link.submenu.length}"
                ui-jq="sortable"
                ng-init="submenu = link.submenu;"
                ng-include="'inner-list.html'"
            ></ul>
        </li>

    </script>
```

and this is the jQuery UI passthrough:

```
linksManager.value('ui.config', {
    jq: {
        sortable: {
            connectWith: '.ng-list-level',
            dropOnEmpty: true,
            placeholder: 'sortable-nav-items-placeholder'
        },
        droppable: {
            tolerance: 'touch',
            over: function () {
                $(this).children('ul.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
            },
            out: function () {
                $(this).children('ul.empty').addClass('hidden');
            },
            drop: function () {
                $(this).children('ul.empty').removeClass('empty');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit of an Angular newb myself, but hey, let's learn together.

Take a good look at [AngularUI's Sortable Directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/modules/directives/sortable/sortable.js), which is literally just an AngularJS wrapper for the jQueryUI sortable plugin.

I also found [this tutorial-like article](http://css.dzone.com/articles/drag-and-drop-angularjs-using) that covers the same topic (using jQueryUI's sortable plugin with angular, and getting binding to work).

Basically, in your directive's linking function, you use `scope.$watch` to keep an eye on changes to your model, and you use `scope.$apply` to update your model when the elements are sorted via the plugin.

Comment: Thanx for the resources! It seems the best solution would be to read their implementation and go on from there